# Iota ZeroMQ consumer

Tags: iota-network, iri-legacy-api, java

I would like to consume events from my Iota Zmq node. Can somebody help me to do it?
I enabled Zmq on my iota node by adding those lines in my iota.ini file :

```
ZMQ_ENABLED = true
ZMQ_PORT = 5555
```

I wrote a java code to consume events from Iota.

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

public class hwclient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);


        ZMQ.Socket requester = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
        requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
        requester.subscribe("tx");

        while(true){
            byte[] reply = requester.recv(0);
            System.out.println("Received " + new String(reply) );
        }
}
```

Here is the output :

```
Received tx IMRGHSFJUXITJDQPRWEKDUNUTUKHZAH9GDSGMMNWSBQDQTRMQMWGQHWBDLYJGQOWPPTHUND9NKIWA9999 GHU9DEKYVCWMXCHZSFBJRGEPFPXLHZILQSHTHMQRTHHDVUGEPLACJKEYDGZEWKSSZAHXJIHMDHHKWPLRA -28000000 FUJITSU99999999999999999999 1518709734 1 3 JEPCONFYKXWSFJKICXDCKPHQJLDPVULCQFCIYILCNHPKFLBVVSWDKOTYZJIREHHUZ9BYTZ9IKJPXCVSA9 SHJTYLOUEYEMZCNGUJWVOLNVQRESMODFFZUVGTPUJLMWGAXGDIFIRDX9DZLEWNQOXXF9EPRMVGRYZ9999 MNKWAFLRGJEKHEOBNGZENCUZBQKYQTDKGDALVDYFYIWJTC9JSTSPMHFQ9LRSYGQSTKSREEBIENGEZ9999 1518709795728
Received tx SHJTYLOUEYEMZCNGUJWVOLNVQRESMODFFZUVGTPUJLMWGAXGDIFIRDX9DZLEWNQOXXF9EPRMVGRYZ9999 GHU9DEKYVCWMXCHZSFBJRGEPFPXLHZILQSHTHMQRTHHDVUGEPLACJKEYDGZEWKSSZAHXJIHMDHHKWPLRA 0 FUJITSU99999999999999999999 1518709734 2 3 JEPCONFYKXWSFJKICXDCKPHQJLDPVULCQFCIYILCNHPKFLBVVSWDKOTYZJIREHHUZ9BYTZ9IKJPXCVSA9 IQZJZFXI9ILJIXKTIZCKHLSFRLSJT9QAD9ODNELQKQTZOKRPMBEFOYBOPYAQFMGJITRQODLKFBCX99999 MNKWAFLRGJEKHEOBNGZENCUZBQKYQTDKGDALVDYFYIWJTC9JSTSPMHFQ9LRSYGQSTKSREEBIENGEZ9999 1518709795730
Received tx HWRIZHP99IGYDPLGL99PHENUOQTAFFIDEDDCEAQIYDIJIHTOEDSXHOJFSLATMEBFVPCSVWTVCBJD99999 IOTASPAM9DOT9COM9999999999EPCRCYAIECWCNP9TEXEZMFRNDHYTGGDOSMEYGNIJOPXOOSGZUZRJRAE 0 GYC99999999IOTASPAM9DOT9COM 1518709794 0 0 EUXAXCY9HXYBIVEFVJIBHTQA9YOQTVJZAXUZIDUABDLOUSVTAKNIXHIAJELAAWXBDHBQTATYDFGJZICPD JMY9ENSJVTZHWOARQCVSMAFXBLZHSGNEPDTQSJL9UXSAKNNMSODXR9LYEJTTMOPQJUVAZCVJXRKLZ9999 FYNDHEWNKARCZLWY9AREAAKLJHGWVKFHM9Q9AKZZYIXQSEBGUAUFONCBIJ9QDGHUPDXOICGBHPPOZ9999 1518709796597
Received tx BZBAKG9ADEAHPAAEINWKXEHIFTYFAWMXSQAIFORQTN9VWPDXGDIKTIUDH9RFEMIGFLKBUZKDVJM999999 EREBUS999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 0 999999999999999999999999999 1518709792 0 0 POXLEAPZZGXHJQAR9WXTOWAEPRUKKPBUMWOVKDW9HJ9PNMSCONRDIFNRJJPFIIFLVTHYWOZLXBUMWZCTC THR9VUXZTLOPA9UASTSOMRIIJVSFPZCQBCLT9YLVLYCYZ9DFTASDMRSYY9BIEUNJSCHXHLUELDHD99999 ZMWMJNRVDAFGFLOYPKHEUSFDDKJLHOKAFURJAFBWBIDMZBOTLXRTYTGWQKTQOAGFTECM9QNPSZUZA9999 1518709796754
Received tx FKSJTVQFVXAULNNVDAPLUXUON9THHLSPSUJIHEFFYHTAYZR9IXQFNPJXHVRHBWNFLBYPVVQJIIMVA9999 UBIAMVVHYNBIIDOIXMYWGVQSEFDGYUSWEYZTYKTIMWVYHGTCMEHQJINVEEGIHJ9WPWJVPSVXWHMYIWJRW 332198426 999999999999999999999999999 1518693519 3 3 OFLQWUTZKLQZXJBHEVWCZLWP9OZXHWYXJEBJJRTFGRFBBUHCXYRIIFIKKVIBIPRFVWBURGJ9V9PZVNFLX JMY9ENSJVTZHWOARQCVSMAFXBLZHSGNEPDTQSJL9UXSAKNNMSODXR9LYEJTTMOPQJUVAZCVJXRKLZ9999 BPQXEVSDXCLBOFJWKNBLYUSTMRYFZUNKHVWPDIEOXHIGVEURFFCIU9EKHAAHLGVBRWLFMRODQASPZ9999 1518709799638
Received tx LVHXOFERQOWNWLYAGBXGVJNGH9SULJFZVHRXL9JJWJ9RPDBZHRJWBXASVNJEMBLFMZUJMEKZHLUK99999 MQQKJGCJWFBRJXURYSERTNFVJAJXPLRXOLKMXCOZWIMUD9CVAFVHGSVZODVKNMKAXEDHOSJDRHAUEMURY 0 999999999999999999999999999 1518693503 2 3 OFLQWUTZKLQZXJBHEVWCZLWP9OZXHWYXJEBJJRTFGRFBBUHCXYRIIFIKKVIBIPRFVWBURGJ9V9PZVNFLX FKSJTVQFVXAULNNVDAPLUXUON9THHLSPSUJIHEFFYHTAYZR9IXQFNPJXHVRHBWNFLBYPVVQJIIMVA9999 JMY9ENSJVTZHWOARQCVSMAFXBLZHSGNEPDTQSJL9UXSAKNNMSODXR9LYEJTTMOPQJUVAZCVJXRKLZ9999 1518709799646
```

Please what represents each value? And how can I handle them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each record represents one transaction which was newly received by the node. I'll take apart one single line (which represents [this transaction](https://thetangle.org/transaction/IMRGHSFJUXITJDQPRWEKDUNUTUKHZAH9GDSGMMNWSBQDQTRMQMWGQHWBDLYJGQOWPPTHUND9NKIWA9999) - so you can compare the values there). The Java code in iri that builds these `tx` messages is [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/f021610fc871efd20325ac8fd602b7a408b985d7/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/storage/ZmqPublishProvider.java#L57-L69).

- `tx` - this is a transaction received
- `IMRGHSFJUXITJDQPRWEKDUNUTUKHZAH9GDSGMMNWSBQDQTRMQMWGQHWBDLYJGQOWPPTHUND9NKIWA9999` - transaction hash (to look the transaction up via the API if desired)
- `GHU9DEKYVCWMXCHZSFBJRGEPFPXLHZILQSHTHMQRTHHDVUGEPLACJKEYDGZEWKSSZAHXJIHMDHHKWPLRA` -  address
- `-28000000` - amount
- `FUJITSU99999999999999999999` - tag
- `1518709734` - timestamp of creating bundle (in seconds since epoch)
- `1` - index in bundle
- `3` - number of transactions in bundle
- `JEPCONFYKXWSFJKICXDCKPHQJLDPVULCQFCIYILCNHPKFLBVVSWDKOTYZJIREHHUZ9BYTZ9IKJPXCVSA9` - bundle hash
- `SHJTYLOUEYEMZCNGUJWVOLNVQRESMODFFZUVGTPUJLMWGAXGDIFIRDX9DZLEWNQOXXF9EPRMVGRYZ9999` - trunk transaction hash
- `MNKWAFLRGJEKHEOBNGZENCUZBQKYQTDKGDALVDYFYIWJTC9JSTSPMHFQ9LRSYGQSTKSREEBIENGEZ9999` - branch transaction hash
- `1518709795728` - attachment timestamp (in **milli**second since epoch)

Comment: Thanks. I've already found a good link in javascript but I forgot to add an answer to my question here. Btw "tx" represents the topic I listen to. :)

Comment: @Parker yes, you can listen to other topics if you are interested in tip selection statistics for example. If you want transactions, tx is the right one.

Comment: @mihi Is it possible to subscribe to a specific tag? And do all nodes implement ZMQ?

Comment: Okay, the ZMQ can be enabled/disabled via [configuration](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/f021610fc871efd20325ac8fd602b7a408b985d7/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/Iota.java#L213-L215). Do you know what node operators do in practice?

Comment: since I don't run a node, I don't know what they do and what they use ZMQ for. I doubt that anyone makes his ZMQ port public, though.